# Totally Blank Unity / Microsoft Store Build fails WACK tests

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, app-certification-kit, wack

I have been trying to get a successful build for my game in **Unity 2018.2.1f1** and **Visual Studio 2017 15.8.0**.

After trying unsuccessfully to get a successful build / package / WACK for the windows store with **all/every** different configuration,  I tried a **totally blank** default Unity, UWP platform app, generated a visual studio project. generated some icons, associated it with an app I had in the store. Built it, packaged it and run the WACK tests.

> **FAILED**
>
> **Supported APIs**
>
> **Error Found**: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
>           API ExecuteAssembly in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. WinTest2.exe calls this API.
>           API DllGetActivationFactory in uwphost.dll is not supported for this application type. WinTest2.exe has an export that forwards to this API.
>       Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps violates the Microsoft Store certification requirements.
>       How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Microsoft Store apps. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration or without .NET Native enabled (where applicable) can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration, and with .NET Native enabled if applicable. See the link below for more information:

What do I have to do to make a successful app build that I can actually get into the store. (What configuration, what unity / visual studio versions.) I have tried later versions of **unity 2018.2.1** and **2018.2.2** (i think) and could not get a successful build out of them.

A while ago, i could not get a successful build out of Unity, so I reinstalled Win 10 Pro, Unity and Visual Studio. Still problems persist.

Comment: I have the same problem on VS2017 Community **15.9.4**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to StormBringerStudios I received an answer that works.

> "Just Got **Visual Studio 2017 15.7.6** version. **works** like a charm.
>
> So here is my Solution is anyone will search this kind of problem **DONT** USE VS 2017 **15.8.X**.
>
> **Downgrade** to **15.7.6** and you will be good :)
>
> Microsoft certification also passed."

Comment: Wow, seriously?

Comment: Yes, seriously.

Comment: I submitted my WACK failing app to the MS Store - it seems to have passed validation (on upload), we'll see how the rest of the submission goes.

Comment: Yeah, Should be interesting, Let me know which version you are using, if it passes.

Comment: Successfully published in the store.  My version info here, in the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489028/uwp-app-failing-wack-with-multiple-errors