# UWP App Failing WACK with Multiple Errors

Tags: uwp, wack

In the past I have successfully developed and deployed a few UWP apps to the MS Store.  Currently getting a large number of unexpected failures, of types that I've never had before, when trying to pass the WACK test.

I started this specific project in Nov 2017.  Technically it's not that advanced, from a code perspective I'm not doing anything I haven't successfully passed through WACK before.

- VS 2017 Community v15.8.8
- Project Target (& Min) version: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition 10.0; Build 14393
- (WACK) Kit Version: 10.0.17763.132
- OS Version: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134.0)

**Update: 5-Feb** *I also get failures when trying to pass a brand new application using VS defaults (Target version: 1803 build 17134, min version: Creators update build 15063).  I get a lot less errors but still some unexpected ones.*

**Update: 7-Feb** *This question/answer also helped: [Totally Blank Unity / Microsoft Store Build fails WACK tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875991/totally-blank-unity-microsoft-store-build-fails-wack-tests)*

Errors include (but not limited to):

- **Bytecode generation** Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:

  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Utility.IsPackageWWA(AppXPackage package) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BytecodeGenerationCheck.BytecodeGenerationCheck.ExecuteSharedValidation(String manifestFilePath, String packageFullName) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()
- **Platform version launch** Error Found: The high OS version validation detected the following errors:

  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Utility.LaunchAppTest(String packageFullName, String manifestFilePath, String testName) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.HighOSVersionLaunchCheck.HighOSVersionLaunchCheck.Test(UapApp uapApp) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()
- **App launch** Error Found: The app launch test detected the following errors:

  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Utility.LaunchAppTest(String packageFullName, String manifestFilePath, String testName) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.LaunchAppCheck.LaunchAppCheck.Test(UapApp uapApp) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()

Any ideas?  I've uninstalled my App, and rebooted, still no success.

Comment: If you can generate package successfully, but WACK failed on local machine. You could ignore it and upload your package to dev center directly. If you can pass the MS store WACK online, then there's no problem with your package.

Comment: I might try that as a last resort.

Comment: @Bite - that seems to work; post as Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can generate package successfully, but WACK failed on local machine. You could ignore it and upload your package to dev center directly. If you can pass the MS store WACK online, then there's no problem with your package.

Comment: Exactly.   I had too some problem in the past months in validating locally the apps, but uploading packages to the Store has always been fine.

Comment: I've got the same behavior.  The problematic part is using the WACK locally is a nice check to make sure I haven't made any poor design choices (it's better to know that early so you can course correct before too much code is written).  I ran WACK manually also from the command line which ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I also was able to pass validation following Bite's suggestion. In my case, I was updating one of my Store apps; I ran WACK (10.0.18362.0) locally on the update and encountered a problem similar to the one Adrian describes. I submitted it to the store anyway and it validated.

Comment: please make it look more like an answer.